# Reverse order of an array and return the size of it javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a strange problem. I have to implement a function count(s) which inverts the getNumberSequence function that I have already create. (i.e: count(getNumberSequence(x)) == x, for all integers x > 0). I have my function and I have also the logic to resolve the problem but I don't know how to do it. In my case I want to call the previous string of ordered numbers, split them and call the last number. The problem is, how can I call the return of another method? Here are my codes:

```
function getNumberSequence(number) {
    var result = "";

    if (number <= 0) {
        return result;
    } else {
        var first = true; 
        for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                result += ", ";
            }
            result += i;
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Basically I need the variable result in this case to call it in the other function.

```
function count(s) {
    var d = s. split(', ');
    return d[-1];
}
```

I know that the second code is wrong but I don't know how to fix it. I have implemented a test that is:

```
test( "Count", function() {
    for (i = 1; i<10000; i = i + 10) {
        equal(count(getNumberSequence(i)) , i, "count(getNumberSequence(" +i + ")) should return    " + i);
    }
```

I know that the answer could be stupid but I started javascript yesterday for the first time. Hope you can help me. Thanks to everyone

Comment: How about using native [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method, and [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property?

Comment: Yes I thought the same thing but the problem is always the same.... How can I call the result of the previous function? As I said I'm at the beginning of this subject. The ways to do this exercise are two: or the reverse order and then print everything or split the string and call the last element (As I understand I have just to call the length of the string, is it right?)

Comment: why use a comma separated string instead of a _real_ array?

Comment: I want to go though all cases. I'm doing some random exercises from a book and I saw this exercise

Comment: Your `i` variables are leaking. Make it `var i`!

Comment: @Bergi, just discovered that trying to implement the test in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to pass a number, say `10`, into the first function and have that return a string of numbers up to `10` and then for `count` to read that string and return `10` (as an integer) again? This will do the trick. It takes the string, splits it, and pops out the last number converting it to an integer before it returns it.

```
function count(seq) {
  return parseInt(seq.split(', ').pop(), 10);
}
```

I could rewrite it like this:

```
function count(seq) {

  // create an array
  var arr = seq.split(', ');

  // grab the last element (a string)
  var lastElement = arr.pop();

  // convert the string to an integer
  var convertedInteger = parseInt(lastElement, 10);

  // return the integer
  return convertedInteger;
}
```

If you wanted to use reverse and grab the first element, do this:

```
function count(seq) {
  return parseInt(seq.split(', ').reverse()[0], 10);
}
```

Or use [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) which does the same thing:

```
function count(seq) {
  return parseInt(seq.split(', ').reverse().shift(), 10);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/61js76fL/)

Comment: Ok I'll give you an example. Suppose I insert in the getNumberSequence the number 10. I will have a string "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" then I want to call this string in the count, split it, reverse and call the first value which will be 10. I will explain it to you because I'm not sure if I understand your function

Comment: @pp94, in my function you don't need to reverse it. `pop` pops off the last number from the array.

Comment: Ok the fact is that the test will put, instead of seq, the numberCount function with a particular value

Comment: Ok now it returns something but I don't know the error now is in the test. It says count(getNumberSequence(2)) should return 2 but have 1.
I don't understand this problem of incongruence. It makes no sense

Comment: Thanks Andy for everything

Comment: Like Bergi says, you need to `var` your `i` variable in your loops as it leaks into the global scope and ruins the test (where you're also trying to use `i`).

Comment: Strange thing but it wasn't the problem (don't say to me why).This is a test taken from an e-book. I solved the problem. Thanks